# $1<a<n-1$ and $\gcd(a, 10) = 1$, how many integers $a$ respect these conditions ?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

$a, n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I would like to find the number of integers $a$ such that : 
$1 < a < n-1$ such that : $\gcd(a, 10) = 1$.

Here is what I've done so far :

$10 = 5 \cdot 2$, hence : $[n/2]$ integers are such that : $\gcd(a, 2) = 1$, moreover there are : $[[n/5]/2]$ multiple of $5$ that are odd. 
So maybe we have something like : 
$$|\{1 < a < n-1, \gcd(a,10) = 1\}| = n-[[n/5]/2]-[n/2]$$
But I am not quite sure...

Comment: subtract multiple of 2, 5.

Comment: This is what I've done

Comment: You need to add back multiples of $10$.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer must be something like $n-1-[n/5]-[n/2]+[?/?]$ by thinking duplicate.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/839130)

Comment: @StubbornAtom I give a hint about "duplicate", though.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*: An integer number is coprime with $10$ if and only if its last digit is $1$, $3$, $7$ or $9$.

Comment: OK, but it's hard to see the formula behind that...